# Sum DataTable columns of type string

Tags: c#-2.0

How do I calculate Sum of two rows in `DataTable` which is of type string ?
in my case I cannot change column type.
I tried these :

1)

```
object objSum;    
objSum = dt.Compute("Sum(WeightRate)", "");
```

2)

```
decimal total = (decimal)dt.Compute("SUM( [WeightRate] )", "");`
```

But no luck...

My table :

> Weightrate         No.Ofvehicles
>     350.50              50
>     205.00               40

I need result as

> Weightrate         No.Ofvehicle
>     555.50              90

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Compute method allows for some rudimentary type conversion:

```
var sum = dt.Compute("Sum(Convert(WeightRate, 'System.Int32'))");
```

See the MSDN help on [DataColumn Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) for more information about what you can do with a Compute method call.

**Edit** Having re-read your question, you'll probably want to convert to System.Decimal rather than System.Int32, but hopefully you got that. ;-)

Comment: @Matt: I am sorry for opening this question again. On another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928748/syntaxerrorexception-using-datatable-compute-method-to-get-sum-of-a-converted-st/), the same thing didn't work. Could you please check, if your code will work with the link pasted above? Thanks!!

Comment: Sir its not work for me. i tried in vb.net  `Dt.Compute("Sum(Convert(deliveredqty,'System.Double'))"))` its how compile time error `Arugument of filter is missing` so i changed like this `Dt.Compute("Sum(Convert(deliveredqty,'System.Double'))",""))` But it not work sir

Comment: The above answer doesn't work now. Here is a solution - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/603a56e6-698a-40a5-9c2c-6538641627fd/how-to-convert-a-datatable-column-from-string-to-int-?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using the below:

var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["WeightRate"]));