# SyntaxErrorException using DataTable.Compute method to get sum of a converted string column

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable that has a string type column filled with valid numeric values and I need to get a sum of those values.  Please understand that if I was in control of the data I'm working with in this instance, I would not have used a string column to store "Cost" but that is the unfortunate reality.  I've been using the DataTable.Compute method with the "SUM(Convert([Column],'DataType'))" expression and no filter.  The problem is that I get the following exception:

> System.Data.SyntaxErrorException - Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.

I've put together a small block of code that successfully reproduces the issue that I'm having.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Cost", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3.25" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0.75" });

            object TotalCost = dt.Compute("Sum(Convert(Cost,'System.Decimal'))", "");
```

One last note, I am restricted to .NET 2.0 so using LINQ to get through this isn't an option at the present time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler to define the column data type to store number, than string?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Cost", typeof(System.Decimal));
dt.Rows.Add(1M);
dt.Rows.Add(3.25M);
dt.Rows.Add(0.75M);

decimal TotalCost = (decimal)dt.Compute("Sum(Cost)", "");
```

**EDIT**: How about adding a new temporary column to do the conversion, summing it up & removing it?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Cost", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3.25" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0.75" });

// temporary column for converting string to decimal
dt.Columns.Add("CostNumeric", typeof(decimal), "Convert(Cost, 'System.Decimal')");
// using temporary column to do aggregation
object TotalCost = dt.Compute("Sum(CostNumeric)", "");

dt.Columns.Remove("CostNumeric");
Console.WriteLine(TotalCost);
```

Comment: It certainly would! But as I stated in my question, I don't have control over the DataTable being passed to me in my actual program.  The block of code I wrote for this question is just a simplified replication of what I'm dealing with.

Comment: Thanks Shahkalpesh, that seems like it will work out nicely.  Although, I find it strange that the method I use throws an exception even though it was an accepted answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708299/sum-datatable-columns-of-type-string). We may never know, haha.  Thanks for your help, I will end up using this method!

Comment: @Hagelt18: I have asked Matt (from the link provided above) if his answer works?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it like this:

```
decimal TotalCost = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //if you don't replace "." for "," the convert method will understand it as a miller points and will turn 3.25 in 325
    TotalCost += Convert.ToDecimal(row["Cost"].ToString().Replace(".", ","));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have considered resorting to that but I'm trying to find something more efficient since I will have to do this for several columns and an indefinite number of rows.

Also, I don't know what a miller point is and I couldn't find anything on it when I googled it...but when I call Convert.ToDecimal("3.25") it properly returns 3.25M.

Comment: Hmmm, got it. I'll see if I can figure out something to help you.